# How to redirect to another page with a hidden value using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, redirect

I have to redirect to another page while passing a hidden value to that page.

Form post is not working as the page links are being modified say `#!/newpage.php` etc.

```
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="newpage.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Send ID" />
  </form>
```

Instead I want to use code similar to following.

```
  $(document).ready(function()
   {
           $("#sendid").click(function()
            {
                 if($("#pid").val().length == 0)
                 {
                      alert("Error!");
                 }
                 else
                 {
                      $.post("newpage.php",
                      { 
                           pid:$("#pid").val(),
                           window.location.href("#!/newpage.php");
                      }
               }
          }
    });
```

So basically we need to send the hidden value to `newpage.php` and redirect on button clik.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({   
    type: "POST",   
    url: 'newpage.php',   
    data: {pid:$("#pid").val()},   
    always: function( data ) {
       window.location.href("#!/newpage.php");
       //or if you want to submit form
       $("#form1").submit();   
    },
    dataType: 'json' 
});
```

not sure what do you want to achive, but hope this code above will help you.

Comment: Why json datatype? And typically, if you're not sure what they want, it might not be the best idea to answer the question. You should know the code is right, not just hope.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. But its not working or maybe I'm not able to properly implement it. 
Can you look into it again.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button').submit(sendid);
function sendid()
{
    $.ajax( {
   url: 'newpage.php',
   type: "post",
   data:  {"pid":$("#pid").val()},
   cache: false,
   success: function(response){
         window.location.href("#!/newpage.php");   
   }
}
```